# Adwords Remarketing - multiple sites - GTM

Tags: tags, google-ads-api, google-tag-manager

Question on Adwords remarketing setup. Currently we run adwords capaigns across several sites and languages from the same adwords account. In GTM each site has its own container with page tags, etc.

Do i just use the same remarketing tag across all containers or is it beneficial to create a new remarketing tag for each site separately?﻿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep you can just use the same single tag across all sites.  There is no compelling reason to have different tags for each site.

If you need to fine-tune the audiences later on based on visits to individual/specific sites, you can use the filter tools inside of AdWords to set up rules that use that single tag.